# Measuring impedance frequency response on Low Power Board

Tags: frequency, impedance, low-power

I have a low power board (2.1V DC). It runs a micro, some sensors, etc. I am interested in plotting out the impedance frequency response of the overall board so I can tell where the impedance dips. This will let me know any problem areas in my bulk capacitors or layout. I am curious how to go about this, and yes I know I can do a simulation, but would like real data.

Comment: Rent one of these http://teledynelecroy.com/sparq/  Although from your description of your board doing this analysis is probably overkill.

Comment: Also a fantastic suggestion. That is a serious piece of equipment and I will definitely give it a try for more in depth characterization. It's never overkill if it looks interesting :)

Comment: Yeah it's a nice toy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, I think what you are trying to do is verify that you have appropriate bypassing and that the layout is not susceptible to some coupling.

Getting the impedance frequency response sounds trickier unless you already have equipment to do that. What I would do is first check the frequency response of the bypass caps. You might be able to get away with using a signal generator as a power source. Put in the required DC offset and add an additional sine wave. Ensure that the peaks / lows are within spec and don't trip a UVLO or something like that. Get a nice probe & scope and stick it on the node of interest (MCU VDD for example). Measure the amplitude of the signal at the node and you can calculate how much attenuation is occurring. From this you can calculate your power supply rejection ripple (PSRR) or whatever value you want.

Alternatively, inject some white noise into the system, and grab a spectrometer of the node of interest. Once again, you'll be able to see how the board is rejecting unwanted signals.

Comment: You hit all my main points in the limited equipment and keeping the test within spec. The attenuation will double as a system test as you say, and I should be able to map out impedance dips though it will take a while. Thanks for a simple and creative response.

Comment: As a side note, a signal generator will have limited current output. If you are finding you are running into that current limit you can do the following. Run it off a normal power supply. Use the same signal generator trick but stick a series capacitor between the signal output and the power supply. This will AC couple the signal onto the power line.

Comment: Good point. It is a very low power system, with under 20mA draw a majority of the time, so I did not run into this problem. Already tested it and it worked great. Injected 720mV PP while isolating the stuff that didn't suite and managed system level attenuation measurements.